# How to do division of very large integers rounded to nearest integer?

Tags: python

I have two very large integers x, y.  How can I compute x/y rounded to the nearest integer in pure Python?  x//y will give me the correct answer but rounded down.

The numbers are big enough that round(x/y) will not give the correct answer due to floating point precision.

I would like to avoid using any libraries if at all possible.   Although Decimal would work, I am using pypy and Decimal is very slow in pypy. If there were a suitable library that was fast in pypy I would be happy to use it.

Examples:

```
x1 = 10**100 - 1
x2 = 10**100 + 1
y = 2 * 10**100

assert divide(x1, y) == 0
assert divide(x2, y) == 1

assert divide(x1, -y) == 0
assert divide(x2, -y) == -1

assert divide(-x1, y) == 0
assert divide(-x2, y) == -1

assert divide(-x1, -y) == 0
assert divide(-x2, -y) == 1
```

`def divide(x, y): return round(x/y)` gives `0` for all 8 test cases, failing the `x2` test cases.

Comment: result = (x + y / 2) / y.

Comment: @Elec1 that does not give the right answer.

Comment: How do you want to break ties? Like for 2.5 or 3.5.

Comment: @KellyBundy I actually don’t mind if .5 rounds up or down.

Comment: Can you add an example for this?

Answer (score 3):

Check the remainder:

```
def divide(a, b):
    if b < 0:
        # Things are a bit more convenient with b and remainder non-negative.
        a, b = -a, -b

    quotient, remainder = divmod(a, b)

    if remainder * 2 > b:
        quotient += 1
    elif remainder * 2 == b:
        # Exactly halfway between two options.
        # Handle this case however is appropriate for your use case.
        # For example, round-half-to-even would be as follows:
        if quotient % 2:
            quotient += 1
    # else no adjustment needed

    return quotient
```

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
def round_to_nearest_int(x, y):
    if x % y <= y / 2:
        return x // y
    else:
        return x // y + 1
```

Here, `%` is used to figure out if number is less than or greater than equal to 0.5. If its less than 0.5 then `x // y` else `x // y + 1`.

Example:

```
round_to_nearest_int(10, 7) => 1
round_to_nearest_int(9, 10) => 1 # here if we do 9 // 10 it will give 0
```

Comment: y/2 will be a float which could be very far from the right answer.

Comment: Can you add some example in your question?

Comment: No need to compare with half of something, when you can double it instead. See @user2357112's answer.

Comment: ok, understood let me check it once.